# Specify Branch in Pipeline job

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Can we read the parameter value and use it in branch specifier in Pipeline Job. Need to specify the git branch as a parameter and use the same in branch specifier in pipeline job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your parameter is named `gitBranch`, then you can add it like this:

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
         branches: [[name: params.gitBranch]]
         ..)
```

Comment: I need to try this. Are you mentioning for pipeline job or multi branch

Comment: Pipeline one, but it should work for multi branch pipeline too.

Comment: I was trying this and I am getting an error as `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: git for class: groovy.lang.Binding`

Comment: What is the exact code that you are trying to execute?

Comment: It was a stupid mistake from my side. I missed to add params. Before the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following in groovy to pull the current branch in my multipipeline Jenkinsfile:

```
git branch: env.BRANCH_NAME, credentialsId: '[credential string]', url: 'git@github.com:[user]/[repo].git'
```

The helpful [pipeline snippet generator](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/05/31/pipeline-snippetizer/) will show you the correct credential string and url.